# Printing (Char*)(Void*) works in main program but not function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

I have an array of structures called `node`s. Each node contains a field of a void pointer.

In a function I take the specific node and assign the void pointer to a string, that string containing the result of a decimal that has been converted to binary.

The issue is that accessing and printing that void pointer cast to a char* works fine in the function to assign the void* to a new char* AND prints fine when returning back to the main function. However it does not print properly when I try to print it in a separate function that take the node[] and index of the array as arguments.

To help illuminate confusion this is the simplified version of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define listSize 100

typedef struct Node
{
    union{
        void *dataPtr;
        int countr;
    }dataItem;
    int  link;
}node;

void loadData(node*);
void printFunc(node[], int);

void main()
{
    struct Node Stack[listSize];

    loadData(&Stack[0]);

    //This prints fine
    char * temp;
    temp = (char*)(Stack[0].dataItem.dataPtr);
    printf("\nMain():  Stack[empty].dataItem.dataPtr = %s\n", temp);


    printFunc(Stack, 0);

}

void loadData(node* link){
    char string[220];

    int n, c, k, i;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    i = 0;

    for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        k = n >> c;

        if (k & 1){
            string[i] = '1';
            i++;
        }
        else{
            string[i] = '0';
            i++;
        }
        if (c == 0){ string[i] = '\0'; }//end the string
    }

    link->dataItem.dataPtr = &string;

    //This prints fine:
    printf("\nLoadData(): link->dataItem.dataPtr is now %s\n", (char *)(link->dataItem.dataPtr));
}


void printFunc(node Stack[], int newLink){

    //This does not work!
    char* temp;
    temp = (char*)(Stack[newLink].dataItem.dataPtr);
    printf("\npush():  Stack[newLink].dataItem.dataPtr %s\n", temp);
}
```

Output:
[image: Output of program]

I am also compiling in Visual Studios 2012. I know that sometimes pointers in GCC to the Microsoft C compiler can be a little different.

What am I writing that is making the program unable to print the void* cast as a char* in the `printFunc` function?

Comment: `link->dataItem.dataPtr = &string;` - That doesn't work. First, you don't need the `&`, because the local array will decay into a pointer. Second, and more importantly, you assign a local array to a pointer to be used outside of its scope. That's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens in your code:

As you call to the LoadData function, it allocates `string[220]` on the stack. The stack then looks like this:

```
[main variables] [LoadData variables, including string[220]] <-- HEAD
```

Then load data exits. As it exits, it moves the stack pointer back. At this time your stack looks like this:

```
[main variables] <-- HEAD [LoadData variables, including string[220]]
```

Note, that in your case `string` is still technically there, it can be read and accessed, but this is purely by coincidence and depends on your complier implementation. Some other compiler might have immediately erased it, or optimized it in some other way. As soon as a function exits, there should be no pointers left pointing to variables allocated on the stack! Your code violates this, by leaking a pointer to the stack-allocated `string`. At this time your code is already in the danger zone! The moment you access that pointer, your code can crash, your computer can catch fire, or the world can cease to exist.

But in your particular case `string` happens to be still accessible, so as you print it from `main`, it appears to be printed properly. It gives you an illusion that everything is fine. The illusion disappears as you call to the `printFunc`, because now it will occupy the stack space where `string` was located!

```
[main variables] [printFunc variables] <-- HEAD
```

Note, that the `string` is now gone! But your `Stack` variable still points to that memory, which now contains garbage!

How to address it? Well, if you plan to return something from the function, you need to either allocate string for that on the calling side:

```
int main {
    ...
    char string[220];
    LoadData(&Stack[0], string); // and make LoadData use the argument string instead of creating its own
    ...
}
```

or make LoadData allocate the string on the heap:

```
char* LoadData (...) {
    char* string = malloc(220);
    ...
}
```

In which case do not forget to deallocate it in `main` later:

```
int main() {
    loadData(&Stack[0]);
    ...
    free(Stack[0].dataItem.dataPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the `dataPtr` to a string that is declared on the stack on this line:

```
link->dataItem.dataPtr = &string;
```

Once you are out of scope you have undefined behavior. You need to allocate memory for the string on the heap.

```
char *string = malloc(220);

... 

//then assign it directly
link->dataItem.dataPtr = string;
```

You will also need a function to free all of your data when you are done with it.

Comment: ... and `strcpy()`, or just use something like [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) if amicable.